# Suppose T(k) denotes the smallest number of steps needed to move from k to 100.Find y & z such that T(9)= 1+ min (T(y),T(z)).

Tags: recreational-mathematics, contest-math

Suppose you want to move from 0 to 100 on the number line. In each step, you ***either 
move right by a unit distance*** or you take a ***shortcut***.  A shortcut is simply a pre-specified pair of integers ***i , j*** with ***i < j***.Given a shortcut ***i , j*** if you are at position ***i*** on the number line, you may directly move to ***j***. Suppose ***T(k)*** denotes the ***smallest number of steps needed to move*** from ***k to 100***. Suppose further that there  is at most 1 shortcut involving any number, and in particular ***from 9  there is a shortcut to 15.*** 
Let   y and z  be such that 
***T(9)= 1+ min (T(y),T(z))***.

Then what is the value of the product ***yz*** ?

Comment: Just could not write exact Title because of restriction of 150 characters. Please help me answering this question didn't get the concept of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ and $z$ are $10$ and $15$, because from $9$, you can move to $100$ via $10$ in $1+T(10)$ steps or via $15$ in $1+T(15)$ steps. Taking the minimum gives $T(9)=1+\min(T(10),T(15))$. Now, we have $yz=10\cdot 15=150$.

EDIT:
A problem like this is usually solved using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). In this case, we calculate all $T(i)$ starting at $T(100)$ and going down to $T(0)$.
It takes $0$ steps to reach $100$ from $100$, so $T(100)$ is $0$. It takes $1$ step from $99$, so $T(99)=1$. Now, if there is a bridge from $i$ to $j$ ($i<j$), then, from $i$ we can go to $i+1$ and to $j$. We know it takes $1+T(i+1)$ steps if we go via $i+1$ and $1+T(j)$ steps if we go via $j$. We take the minimum of those two because we want to minimize the total number of steps. Thus, $T(i)=1+\min(T(j),T(i+1))$. If you wanted, you could go down to $T(0)$ and calculate the minimal number of steps needed to go from $0$ to $100$.

Comment: Dear "Ragnar" your answer is correct but could you please explain the problem & its solution a bit more.I shall be thankful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much "Ragnar" for your help.Now I got the gist of the problem.Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, $yz=y \cdot 15$ for $0 \leq y \leq 15$ are all possible answers given the current wording of the problem.  This is because $min(T(y),T(15))=T(15)$ for all $0 \leq y \leq 15$.